# не отображается текст в textbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Делал стиль для textBox, а текст там не отображается, что нужно добавить? Что-то явно упускаю, находил решения таких проблем но не помогло.

```xml
<Grid.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="Border" Borderbrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="30,0,30,0">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Что нужно еще вписать? Пробывал разные вариации не работает. Когда стиль убираю всё работает.
Если вводить текст по дефолту его не видно но он там есть так как проверку на значения прошел.

Comment: Открываем [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates), и смотрим что вы забыли добавить. Вот прям первое, `PART_ContentHost - Текст TextBox отображается в этом элементе.`, где он у вас?

Comment: Сделаль спасибо